# Select records that dont exist in a table but also include those that exist with where clause exclusion

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tiers. One tier is for customers who earned at least 1 point, another one is for customers who has at least 1000 points.

I want to get records of customers who has points >= 950 and < 1000. I am planning to move them to the second tier as a bonus. I imported customers lately and they were not automatically added in the first tier even when they have at least 1 point.

When I do my query, it doesn't include the ones that I imported because they dont exist in the **customer_vip_tiers** table.

```
tier 1 id = 1733
tier 2 id = 1734
```

> 

```
select
       c.id,
       c.email,
       sum(p.reward_points) as total_points,
       vt.name,
       cvt.tier_id

from vip_tiers_settings vts
left join customers c on c.merchant_id = vts.merchant_id
left join customers_vip_tiers cvt on c.id = cvt.customer_id
left join vip_tiers vt on vt.id=cvt.tier_id
left join perks p on p.customer_id = c.id
                        and p.created_at >= coalesce(vts.custom_start_date,0)
                        and p.completed = 1
                        and p.reversed = 0
                        and p.expired = 0

where
c.merchant_id = 50506
and cvt.tier_id != 1734

group by c.id having sum(p.reward_points) >= '950' and sum(p.reward_points) < '1000'

;
```

My understanding is that they dont get the records of those who are not in the tier because of the **cvt.tier_id != 1734** clause in my where because they dont have records in the customers_vip_tiers table. How do I also get the ones that dont have records in that table?

Comment: Does your vip_tiers_settings table has those customers?

Comment: no. it's only the settings for the tiers. @user3315556

Comment: So, you have imported the customers in customer table? if so do they have merchant_id?

Comment: @user3315556 yes they do have merchant id

Comment: I think one fix can be you can change the join from left join on customers c to a right join.

Comment: @user3315556 got the answer already. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

I got rid of **cvt.tier_id != 1734**.

```
select
       c.id,
       c.email,
       sum(p.reward_points) as total_points,
       vt.name,
       cvt.tier_id

from vip_tiers_settings vts
left join customers c on c.merchant_id = vts.merchant_id
left join customers_vip_tiers cvt on c.id = cvt.customer_id
left join vip_tiers vt on vt.id=cvt.tier_id
left join perks p on p.customer_id = c.id
                        and p.created_at >= coalesce(vts.custom_start_date,0)
                        and p.completed = 1
                        and p.reversed = 0
                        and p.expired = 0

where
c.merchant_id = 50506
and c.id not in(select customer_id from customers_vip_tiers cvv where cvv.merchant_id=50506 and cvv.tier_id=1734)

group by c.id having sum(p.reward_points) >= '950' and sum(p.reward_points) < '1000';
```